# EaselJS how to update text

Tags: javascript, html, web, createjs, easeljs

I'm trying to update the circles and text above each circle when mouseoveer event happens, however I only successfully update the circles, but not sure about how to update the text.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  var circle = new createjs.Shape();
  var r = 7;
  var x = window.innerWidth * Math.random();
  var y = window.innerHeight * Math.random();
  var color = colors[Math.floor(i % colors.length)];
  var alpha = 0.2 + Math.random() * 0.5;
  circle.color = color;
  circle.alpha = alpha;
  circle.radius = r;
  circle.graphics.beginFill(color).drawCircle(0, 0, r);
  circle.x = x;
  circle.y = y;


  var txt = new createjs.Text(i.toString(), "11px Arial", "#FFF");
  txt.x = x - 4;
  txt.y = y - 18;

  var con = new createjs.Container();
  con.addChild(circle, txt);

  con.addEventListener("mouseover", function(event) {
    event.target.graphics.clear().beginFill(event.target.color).drawCircle(0, 0, 15).endFill();
    event.target.text = "dsfasd";
    stage.update(event);
  });

  stage.addChild(con);
}
```

Comment: Consider using Graphics commands to update your shape fill instead: http://blog.createjs.com/new-command-approach-to-easeljs-graphics/

Answer (score 0):

In your listener, `target` refers to the container itself. But `event.target.text` is not a reference to the text object added as a child inside it. In order to access the second child, you need to do `event.target.children[1]`.

Comment: recommend `getChildAt(1)` instead of accessing the children directly

Comment: That is indeed true, I forgot about that one.